# Problem with "No View Found.." when working with Settings Preference

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences, settings

Rookie developer here.
Trying to learn with SharedPreference and Settings Options. I´m facing error message with View No found for fragment.

This is my code related with the issue; I have been checking for similar issues through this site but my knowledge is very basic to get oriented to solve the problem.
thanks in advance for your comments!

In my Activity;

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
   val id = item.itemId
   when (id) {
       R.id.action_settings -> {

           supportFragmentManager
               .beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.action_settings, MySettingsFragment())
               .commit()
       }
       else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
   }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
   }
```

MySettingsFragment

```
package com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra.utilities

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra.R
class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

fragment_settings.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".utilities.MySettingsFragment">

</FrameLayout>
```

Error Message obtained

```
2020-11-08 19:35:55.979 20322-20322/com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra, PID: 20322
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080041 (com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra:id/action_settings) for fragment MySettingsFragment{8621cad} (9e68a7a2-fa38-432f-b3f2-e368c60dae30) id=0x7f080041}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:315)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
2020-11-08 19:35:56.010 20322-20322/com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20322 SIG: 9
```

Adding full MainActivity.class

```
package com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.khaxapplication.rfid_api_zebra.utilities.MySettingsFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
     }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId
    when (id) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {

            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.action_settings, MySettingsFragment())
                .commit()
        }
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }


}
```

Layout for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever layout you are using for your Activity does not have a View with ID "`action_settings`" in it.

If "fragment_settings.xml" is what you were using for your activity, you need to give the FrameLayout an ID property.

Since `R.id.action_settings` exists, you must have it in one of your layout files somewhere. Maybe you have applied the wrong layout in your activity.

Comment: Hi Tenfour04. Thanks a lot for your fast reply. I updated full class for main activity and its layout. As you can see, it´s a simple starting demo example for Android Studio when using drawers menu. The layout for MainActivity is already uploaded. I was following indeed this example.   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings